# 503 error when trying to login joomla 3.3.1

Tags: php-fpm, login, joomla, 503-error

I'm facing a strange issue on joomla and would need help to solve it :

The frontoffice side is working fine but when trying to log in backoffice, I get a HTTP 503 Error :

```
[Wed Jul 29 17:41:02.023862 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 32285] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client <client IP>:55665] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: http://my-website/administrator/index.php
```

http://my-website/administrator/index.php is the backoffice login page. I can access to it before login but I get the 503 error after login with successfull credentials :

Access before login :

```
GET http://my-website/administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1
=> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

On succcessfull login, there is a first redirection and then the 503 :

```
POST http://pmy-website/administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: my-website
...
=> HTTP/1.0 303 See Other
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 09:23:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://my-website/administrator/index.php
...

GET http://my-website/administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: my-website
Referer: http://my-website/administrator/index.php
Cookie: 3f74c53723c2b649b1df9afa77de6e27=tung6luvahdj9v39cdlqmv4kh3
...
=> HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
...
```

A clue : After the 503 error page, I can paste a URL with the section to open. It works ! For example :

```
http://my-website/administrator/index.php?option=com_config
```

The only unavailable URL is index.php without parameter... So I believe that could be an URL Rewriting issue...

My config : Centos 6.6 / joomla v3.3.1 / php 5.4.16 / - apache v2.4.6 + php-fpm.

Thank you in advance if you could help me.
Bests 
Julien

Comment: ve found out that the problem disapears if I deactivave the "Community Builder" modules in Joomla. Especially "Community Builder News", "Community Builder Updates" and "CB Admin Version Checker". Consequently, I think this 503 is the result of the timeout when joomla tries to load the backoffice of these modules and I'm wondering if it's really a system issue